# How to set the location of 2 frames in java

Tags: java, frame

I got a problem. I created two BankAccounts using MVC but when I execute them, the frames open in the same location. How can I set different locations?

Comment: Set their position, isn't there methods? Did you read the docs?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming yours is a Swing GUI (you don't tell us), JFrame has a `setLocation(...)` method, a method that [JFrame API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) will readily show you.

But having said that, be sure to also read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)